# How can I create a new C# Window based on my existing Window?

Tags: c#, forms, window

I know this mite be a bit of a silly question but how do i create another window from my main window in c# windows application? I don't know where to look for this type of questions.

Comment: Are you just looking to show the form, or do you need to create a new form subclass with it's own controls and behaviors separate from your main window?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following to create a new form. Note that I have provided two examples.

```
// This example creates a new Form control. While this Form is open, 
// you cannot gain focus of the parent form.

Form form = new Form();
form.ShowDialog();

// If you want to be able to use both Forms. Then this is what you want:

Form form = new Form();
form.Show();
```

Also, MSDN is your bestest friend: MSDN on [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx).

...And Google.

Comment: Just a note: `new Form()` will create a general form, without anything. You probably want `new WhatEverYourFormClassNameIs()`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
YourForm newForm = new YourForm();
newForm.Show();
```

You have several methods of showing your form. I use `YourForm` as a name here, replace that with the classname of your own form.

Note that a form-class is nothing more than a regular class that can be instantiated like any other class using `new` and inherits all methods from it parent calls (`Form` in this case), which includes the methods `Show` and `ShowDialog`. You can create as many instances of your class (i.e., of your form) as you like.

Comment: lol, well.. when i clicked answer question, yours was already on the page

Answer (score 0):

**I will assume you are using winforms and will walk you through a simple example:**

1. In Solution Explorer, Right Click your project and select Add | New Item...
2. Select the type About Box and you will see a new AboutBox1.cs get generated.
3. Select View | Toolbox to get the Toolbox to appear.
4. On your main form, drag a Button from the ToolBox | Common Controls onto the form.
5. Double click the newly created button to create the Clicked Event.
6. the clicked event type the following code:

```
    AboutBox1 aboutBox = new AboutBox1();
    aboutBox.ShowDialog();
```

This code will declare a variable aboutBox of type AboutBox1 and then instantiate it ( construct it ). Then you call the ShowDialog() method to get it to appear.